# endpointscfg.py gives invalid choice for get_openapi_spec

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

The command I am issuing as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python) is

```
endpointscfg.py get_openapi_spec cfcapi.GreetingApi cfcmelbourne.org
```

The error I get is

```
WARNING:root:An exception has been encountered when attempting to use Application Default Credentials: An error was encountered while reading json file: C:\Code\Video-Archive\requirements.txt (pointed to by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable): No JSON object could be decoded. Falling back on dummy AppIdentityServiceStub.
usage: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\endpointscfg.py
       [-h] {get_client_lib, get_discovery_doc} ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\endpointscfg.py: error: argument {get_client_lib, get_discovery_doc}: invalid choice: 'get_openapi_spec' (choose from 'get_client_lib', 'get_discovery_doc')
```

Comment: What version of endpoints are you using?

Comment: framework v-2 edition

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `endpointscfg.py` that comes with the new Endpoints library. The version you're using is an old version distributed through the Cloud SDK.